# Django Project Connect to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql, google-cloud-sql

I host Database and Django Application separately Server.
I have a Google Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) but I tried many ways to configure Database as Django document

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST': '[Your-Cloud-SQL-Public-IP]',
        'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
        'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
        'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
    }
}
```

by filling it with my credential but cannot connect got error like this:

```
 line 729, in connect
    raise ex.with_traceback(None)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection failed: could not receive data from server: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
could not send SSL negotiation packet: Socket is not connected (0x00002749/10057)
```

Expert please help me to make it works.

I am looking the guideline to configure Django project with Google Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Public IP, you will need to add your Django application's IP address as an [authorized network](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks) of your Cloud SQL instance.

For Private IP if you deploy your Django application within your VPC network the above sample should work as is in your `settings.py` file:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'HOST': '[Your-Cloud-SQL-Private-IP]',
        'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
        'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
        'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
        'SSLMODE': 'require'
    }
}
```

Comment: 2023/09/07 14:31:30 Authorizing with Application Default Credentials
2023/09/07 14:31:31 The proxy has encountered a terminal error: unable to start: [<connectionName>] Unable to mount socket: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

The result above is I was trying with this command 
cloud-sql-proxy.exe <connectionName>

Where can I solve this problem, I have credentails.json and set it as guideline.